# LLVM IR to Python Compiler

Tags: python, compiler-construction, code-generation, llvm, converters

Is there any tool to convert the LLVM IR code to Python code?
I know it is possible to convert it to Javascript (https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki), to Java (http://da.vidr.cc/projects/lljvm/) and I would love to convert it to Python also.

Additionaly if such tool does not exist, could you provide any information, what is the best tool to base on (maybe I should extend the emscripten with other language - Javascript and Python are similar to each other in some terms ;) )

Comment: I'm not aware of such a tool. Although, I would not recommend implementing it as a complete platform backend (it will be an overkill). A simple pass will be sufficient. See the `cbe` pass, for example.

Comment: You are right, it is a good idea. Could you elaborate a little bit more why for example such tool like Emscripten is not written as LLVM pass? It would be a lot easier to use it or embed it in custom compiler.

Comment: probably, they wanted to host the whole thing inside JavaScript. Or they just like coding in JS more than in C++. There are many possible reasons for doing it one way or another. Alternatively, you can do something in between these two options: implement your code generation pass in, say, OCaml, Haskell or Python itself with LLVM bindings.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know any projects that use LLVM Pass (in C++) to convert LLVM IR to some specific language code? I want to base on some existing code unless I'm not an LLVM expert :)

Comment: `cbe` is by far the simplest pass of this kind, I'd recommend to start with it.

Comment: Additional, I would be very thankful for any link describing the cbe pass - I was searching the web for it and I found anything. In the LLVM src I cannot find source of cbe pass also.

Comment: `cbe` had been removed from the recent llvm versions, although it is pretty straightforward to port it from `llvm-3.0`. It is in `lib/Target/CBackend`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to go from LLVM IR to Python code?

Comment: I want simly to write such backend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LLVM up to 3.0 provided a C backend (see `lib/Target/CBackend`) which should be a good starting point for implementing a simple Python code generator.